# How to use Ajax to delete a xml file loaded into the DOM

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm a programming student, I have made this program which uses Ajax to fetch rain.xml which says ("the rain in spain falls mainly on the plain") from the server and then write it into the current page (this part works). But what happens if I want to delete the rain.xml file from the current webpage with another button that says 'Click to remove the  extra text'.

I am struggling to understand if Ajax can delete files or not, 
or if I would have to use Javascript to do this. Advice appreciated thanks.

```
<html>
<head>

<style>

#hidereveal
{
margin:auto;
width:90%;
height:auto;
border: 1px black solid;
text-align:center;
}

p
{
text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="hidereveal">

<p>this is a test, when you click the button and ajax will add in more data 
from the server<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Click to load the 
ajax text</button><button type="button" onclick="removeExtratext()">Click to 
remove the extra text</button></p>


</div>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
document.getElementById("hidereveal").innerHTML += this.responseText;
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "rain.xml", true);
xhttp.send();
}
</script>

<script>
function removeExtratext() {
//????
}
</script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you added to the innerHTML of the element "#hidereveal", you can set/overwrite that innerHTML completely with

```
document.getElementById("hidereveal").innerHTML = "";
```

If you want to keep something else, then create another div element with a different ID inside of hidereveal, and put the XML there.

```
<div id="hidereveal">
    <div id="xml"></div>

    <p>this is a test...</p>
</div>
```

and use the new element to put the XML in

```
document.getElementById("xml").innerHTML += this.responseText;
```

and remove it with the same thing

```
document.getElementById("xml").innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Yes, that removes ALL the text from the whole div, but I want to keep the original text which says "this is a test, when you click the button and ajax will add in more data from the server" and just remove the rain.xml text which I loaded in with ajax which says (even though we can't see it) "the rain in spain falls mainly on the plain"

Comment: Updated my answer, but the jist is you need to create another element that you can put the XML in and remove completely.

Comment: OK Vincent thanks, I managed to get it working by putting in an extra div in the way you suggested. I'm curious if it's technically possible with Javascript to reference my xml added in text WITHOUT creating the extra div though, I think it is but I don't know how!

Comment: @Emma32, it actually is possible. In your specific example you can reference it with `document.querySelector('#hidereveal').lastChild`. 
But to be honest, I personally would not count on, that it will work with different content.
Like I said in my Answer, there are a lot of ways to achieve the same goal. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ajax has nothing to do with deleting files. With Ajax you make a `request` and you will get a `response`.

This response, you added to your existing HTML element `hidereveal` with regular Javascript.

```
document.getElementById("hidereveal").innerHTML += this.responseText;
```

Now you want to remove this specific content from your element, but you have no way to reference it easily.
So I would suggest, that you wrap your new content in a span like this.

```
document.getElementById("hidereveal").innerHTML += `<span id="newContent">${this.responseText}</span>`;
```

Now you have your new content in an element you can reference to and your function `removeExtratext` can look like this.

```
function removeExtratext() {
    let nc = document.querySelector('#newContent');
    nc.parentNode.removeChild(nc);
}
```

and your new Text is gone. 
There are other ways to achieve the same goal as well but I think, this is the easiest way to understand.
I hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks Andre, that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use ajax to change DOM elements. You have used AJAX to get the file and use its contents to change element content with id of "hidereveal".AJAX is just used to GET the data or POST the data to server for example or write to file(and many many more). Just a hint you do not need to create 2 script tags. You can create a file name for example myScripts.js and add a script tag at the end of body.

```html
<body>
  .....
  
  <script src="myScripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

I encourage you to start using javascript event listeners.

```js
document.querySelector('#addContent').addEventListener('click', function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("hidereveal").innerHTML += this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "rain.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
});

document.querySelector('#removeContent').addEventListener('click',function removeExtratext() {
  document.getElementById("hidereveal").innerHTML = "";
});
```

```css
#contentChanger
{
margin:auto;
width:90%;
height:auto;
border: 1px black solid;
text-align:center;
}

p
{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="contentChanger">
    <p>this is a test, when you click the button and ajax will add in more data from the server
      <button type="button" id = "addContent">Click to load the ajax text</button>
      <button type="button" id = "removeContent">Click to  remove the extra text</button>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="hidereveal">
    come to the dark side, we have cookies!
  </div>
<script src='myScripts.js'></script>
</body>
```

I changed your html because you would also removed buttons from the html. I dont have a rain.xml but delete is working. So give it a try. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Visko.